# Saving downloaded .mp4 videos to photos album ios

Tags: ios, video, save

So i have downloaded the .mp4 file to the documents folder in the app. I had successfully saved and played it from the documentsPath, but now I want to save it to the camera roll and use this code :

```
-(void)saveVideoToAlbum:(NSString *)sampleMoviePath{
 if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(sampleMoviePath)){
  UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sampleMoviePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:),nil);
 }
}

-(void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error  contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
 NSLog(@"Finished with error: %@", error);
}
```

it is compatible, since it passed the if bracket and no error log from the second procedure. But I keep getting this lldb abort_with_payload error in my log, can someone help me to solve the problem?

here is some screenshots from the lldb error :

[image: error]

[image: error2]

Comment: any one??? still stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont forget always check your info.plist, and write the necessary permission that needed in your app. for saving video it need Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description. If you are not specify this permission it will crash and there is no error indicating this.